# How can we transfer data from one list to another

Tags: c#, linq

I have Code where i have two Class called ClassA and ClassB and i have two fileds class in Number and Status in both the classes ,
I have created a two List called listA and listB,
I need to query it such that Only the `Status` Property  has  to be transfer from listB to listA using linq / lambda expression.
How can i do that??
Thanks in Advance,
Here is my code snippet

```
class ClassA
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}

class ClassB
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}


 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    List<ClassA> listA = new List<ClassA> ();
    List<ClassB> listB = new List<ClassB>();
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    a.Number = 1; a.Status = false;
    ClassA a2 = new ClassA();
    a2.Number = 1; a2.Status = true;
    ClassA a3 = new ClassA();
    a3.Number = 1; a3.Status = true;
    ClassA a4 = new ClassA();
    a4.Number = 1; a4.Status = true;

    ClassB b1 = new ClassB();
    b1.Number = 2;b1.Status = true;
    ClassB b2 = new ClassB();
    b2.Number = 3; b2.Status = false;
    ClassB b3 = new ClassB();
    b3.Number = 2; b3.Status = true;
    ClassB b4 = new ClassB();
    b4.Number = 3; b4.Status = false;
    listA.Add(a);
    listA.Add(a2);
    listA.Add(a3);
    listA.Add(a4);
    listB.Add(b1);
    listB.Add(b2);
    listB.Add(b3);
    listB.Add(b4);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to map the two classes together in one call. This type of situation is what it was designed for. All you would need to do is create a mapping configuration and then map the two classes. It's a very simple but powerful tool. e.g. Something like this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>()
);

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

List<ClassA> listA = new List<ClassA>();
var listClassB = mapper.Map<List<ClassB>>(listA);
```

Comment: Well spotted. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx), it is quite easy:

```
var classb = from a in listA select new ClassB() { Status = a.Status };
```

This will return a `IEnumerable<ClassB>`, but you can use `ToList` to get your collection as a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

try this following code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<ClassA> listA = new List<ClassA> ();
            List<ClassB> listB = new List<ClassB>();
            ClassA a = new ClassA();
            a.Number = 1; a.Status = false;
            ClassA a2 = new ClassA();
            a2.Number = 1; a2.Status = true;
            ClassA a3 = new ClassA();
            a3.Number = 1; a3.Status = true;
            ClassA a4 = new ClassA();
            a4.Number = 1; a4.Status = true;

            ClassB b1 = new ClassB();
            b1.Number = 2;b1.Status = true;
            ClassB b2 = new ClassB();
            b2.Number = 3; b2.Status = false;
            ClassB b3 = new ClassB();
            b3.Number = 2; b3.Status = true;
            ClassB b4 = new ClassB();
            b4.Number = 3; b4.Status = false;
            listA.Add(a);
            listA.Add(a2);
            listA.Add(a3);
            listA.Add(a4);
            listB.Add(b1);
            listB.Add(b2);
            listB.Add(b3);
            listB.Add(b4);
            listA.AddRange(listB.Select(o => new ClassA() { Status = o.Status }));
        }
```